# Usermeta in wordpress plugin won't save - development

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a plugin, in which I have to save a usermeta. The code for adding and saving the usermeta is below. The usermata field is being shown in the userprofile section, but saving it doesn't do anything. Can someone please help me!

```
function add_adslot_text() { ?>
  <table class="form-table">
      <tr>
          <th><label for="afa_adslot_id">Adslot ID as given by the staff</label></th>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="afa_adslot_id" id="afa_adslot_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'afa_adslot_id', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
            <span class="description">Add your Adslot ID given by the staff.</span>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
<?php }
function save_adslot_text($user_id) {
  update_usermeta( absint( $user_id ), 'afa_adslot_id', wp_kses_post( $_POST['afa_adslot_id'] ) );
}
add_action('show_user_profile', 'add_adslot_text' );
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'add_adslot_text');
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_adslot_text' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_adslot_text' );
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'afa_activate' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and value is saved correctly. Only one problem is there while displaying saved value. `$user` parameter needs to be passed in the function `add_adslot_text`.

Eg:

`function add_adslot_text( $user )`